# Custom names on enum elements

Tags: c#, enums

Suppose there's an *enum* like so.

```
[Flags]
public enum Crazies
{
  One = 2,
  Two = 3,
  Three = 4
}
```

Now, when I force the different values to be stringified, I get the text in the beautiful tongue, which differ considerably from the usual meaning of the numerics. Suppose now that the users prefer a more conventional definition of the natural numbers and wish to see the text "*Two*", although the variable value is *One* (NB it's *Crazies.One*).

What'd be the simplest way to map the stringification of the predefined names of the elements? Right now I'll go with something like the following but I don't really like it.

```
private static String DecrazyfyCrazies(Crazies wrong)
{
  switch(wrong)
  {
    case Crazies.One: return "Two";
    case Crazies.Two: return "Three";
  }
  return "Four";
}
```

Comment: Set the type of your enum to int  `Crazies : int` and just return the enum with return `Crazies.One`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `int` just cast to int

```
return (int)Crazies.One;
```

For more custom string display you can use display name

i.e

```
public enum Crazies
{
  [Display(Name="Custom Name for One")]
  One = 2,
  [Display(Name="Custom Name for Two")]
  Two = 3     
}
```

See more about [Power Up Your Enum](http://geeksharp.com/2011/11/02/power-up-your-enumerations/)

Comment: I was trying to be generic in my question but failed. You got the intention right. +1 for the extra mile and *Display* attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could just cast the enum to an int:

```
return (int)wrong;
```

Comment: That doesn't display the text "*Two*", just the numeric. The intention was to actually set the string displayed to anything I wish.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting the type of your enum.

```
[Flags]
public enum Crazies : int
{
   One = 2,
   Two = 3,
   Three = 4
}
```

Now you can just return the enum with `return Crazies.One`.

There are a several types you can use.

The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: That doesn't display the text "*Two*", just the numeric. The intention was to actually set the string displayed to anything I wish.

Comment: Ah, alright. huMpty duMpty's solution is what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 1):

Create an int getter which returns

```
return (int) enumvar + 1;
```

if you really need words you can just add a static class.. but you don`t need to alter it for every mutation of you crazy enum

```
public static string NumberToWords(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return "zero";

    if (number < 0)
        return "minus " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

    string words = "";

    if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " million ";
        number %= 1000000;
    }

    if ((number / 1000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
        number %= 1000;
    }

    if ((number / 100) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " hundred ";
        number %= 100;
    }

    if (number > 0)
    {
        if (words != "")
            words += "and ";

        var unitsMap = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        var tensMap = new[] { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        if (number < 20)
            words += unitsMap[number];
        else
        {
            words += tensMap[number / 10];
            if ((number % 10) > 0)
                words += "-" + unitsMap[number % 10];
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```